# Pass multiple matrices to a uniform in one call in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, uniform

I've been learning how to use the OpenGL API for the last 2 weeks in Java and I've hit a problem that I just can't seem to solve alone.

In my simple 3D render engine I can render around 10000*132 triangles at around 14-15ms per frame but I'm certain that there's better to be had because 10000 draw calls can't be optimal. Considering that each of these 10000 objects drawn all use the same VAO, wouldn't it be far more efficient to simply send as many of their unique model matrices to the shader as possible in one go before making a draw call to render them all?

So, simply, my question is:
Is there a technique whereby I could send multiple matrices in one go to a shader uniform before making just 1 draw call to render the same bound VAO multiple times using each of the matrices in the uniform to modify their positions?

Comment: Look into [instanced rendering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing), which is what you want. You'll need to upload your transform matrices as an array into a uniform buffer object, then use the `gl_InstanceID​` variable to index it.

Comment: Thank you very much @ColonelThirtyTwo , with your help I've managed to implement instanced rendering into my project with not much difficulty. I actually implemented it slightly different to how you described it though, directly passing the matrices buffer into an attribute allowed me to discard `gl_InstanceID` and the average performance has improved three-fold. Thankyou once again.